# A start job is running for a device that doesn't exist (wireless card) during boot

Tags: boot, wireless, 22.04

Recently took out a wifi card that was in one of my ubuntu server boxes. Now the machine waits 90 seconds while displaying the following during boot:

`a start job is running for /sys/subsystem/net/devices/wlp1s0`

systemd-analyze critical-chain returns:

```
graphical.target @1min 31.833s
└─multi-user.target @1min 31.830s
  └─docker.service @1min 30.988s +838ms
    └─containerd.service @1min 30.612s +348ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.557s
        └─NetworkManager.service @10.518s +103ms
          └─dbus.service @10.513s
            └─basic.target @10.510s
              └─sockets.target @10.508s
                └─libvirtd-ro.socket @10.506s
                  └─libvirtd.socket @10.476s +23ms
                    └─sysinit.target @10.440s
                      └─systemd-sysctl.service @1min 30.724s +6ms
                        └─systemd-modules-load.service @625ms +88ms
                          └─systemd-journald.socket @497ms
                            └─system.slice @410ms
                              └─-.slice @410ms
```

I tried putting `optional: true` in the yaml file in /run/netplan/wpa-wlp1s0.conf with no luck

`ifconfig` and `ip addr` dont show the card

`sudo nmcli radio wifi off` didnt work

Any help is appreciated.